# Sudden drop in battery charge in Manjaro KDE

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, kde

On my Dell XPS 13 9333, I have a problem detecting the "true" battery charge. This problem was in my previous Linux distro Kubuntu and is still present in my current Manjaro with KDE.

The problem is that when the laptop is running on battery power and the charge reaches 25%, it suddenly drops to 2%. [Here](https://yadi.sk/i/itcptf3Iq3PnLw) is the power consumption statistics where the drop is at 16:30 (cannot attach as an image due to lack of "reputation" because I am a new user). These sudden drops have finished my old battery and I replaced it with a new one just a few days ago. However, after replacing the battery, the problem is still there. Any ideas?

It seems to me that the charge is being consumed at an almost constant rate, however, when the battery is about 30%, the indicator starts to show a higher percentage than it actually is. And when the battery is nearly discharged, it suddenly shows the actual charge again (which is 2%). If it is the case should I calibrate battery or something?

P.S. When I used Windows on this laptop there was no such problem.

Comment: Do a vanilla battery reset.  Charge to Full, unplug and let drain to power off, plug in and charge to Full.  Restart the computer.  That should reset the battery.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, @John. However, as far as I know, a complete discharge is bad for battery capacity due to some irreversible processes which happen if it is discharged to 0%. This problem started when I switched from Windows to Linux (before I replaced the battery). So that may be the problem is not in battery, but in how Linux estimates its charge?

Comment: You only do the full discharge once and that will not harm the battery.

Comment: Well, I will give it a try, thank you

Comment: I followed your advice, @John. The problem did not gone and battery health decreased from 97% to 91%.

Comment: So then the battery appears that it needs replacing.